# EPERM error while trying to read fullchain.pem

Tags: node.js, windows, ssl, ssl-certificate, certbot

I'm trying to host an HTTPS website with Node.js on my Windows 10 computer, but Node.js has suddenly stopped being able to read the `fullchain.pem` I obtained using [Let's Encrypt's Certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/).

This is my Node.js code:

```js
const fs = require("fs")
const https = require("https")
const FS_OPTIONS = {
    encoding: "utf-8",
    flag: "r",
}
const key = fs.readFileSync("C:/Certbot/live/subdomain.example.com/privkey.pem", FS_OPTIONS)
const cert = fs.readFileSync("C:/Certbot/live/subdomain.example.com/fullchain.pem", FS_OPTIONS)
https.createServer({ key, cert }, (req, res) => {
    // do stuff...
}).listen(8888)
```

However, when I run it, I receive the following error:

```
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:/Certbot/live/subdomain.example.com/fullchain.pem'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:476:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:377:35)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Users\...\index.js:8:17)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  errno: -4048,
  syscall: 'open',
  code: 'EPERM',
  path: 'C:/Certbot/live/subdomain.example.com/fullchain.pem'
}
```

The only way I can bypass this is by running as administrator, but this is very strange, as this was not required before.

How can I restore this to its previous behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just need to change the access rights of the folder and subfolders of : C:/Certbot

add access to the user running nodejs. for example following this :
https://v2cloud.com/tutorials/how-to-change-folder-permissions-on-windows-2016